# Best way to store secrets in application

Tags: node.js, security, encryption, base64, environment-variables

Which one would be a better way to store secret API keys in  Node js applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `.env` file at root folder and add your all keys, password in that file. To make it secure never ever add file in git repo. Instead add this file in `.gitignore` file so that git ignore this file when you push your changes.

Syntax of .env file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:3000
APP_KEY=SECRETKEY
```

Additionally to access the keys from your .env file is `process.env.APP_KEY`

Its secure method, no one can access this file. I use this way. 
Hope it gives your answer.